# Simulating ARM code

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, arm

I would like to simulate ARM code. For example, I want to run code like this:

```
MOV    R0, #5
ADD    R0, R0, #1
//somehow output R0
```

And it would output 6 on some software on my Ubuntu. Is it possible?

Comment: @PaulR: Asking for a simulator on Ubuntu, not Windows.

Comment: Do you want some kind of library to link into some other application?

Comment: Could you specify what is unclear to you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Keil MDK](http://www.keil.com/arm/mdk.asp) can be used to simulate the ARM codes. It provides a [Simulate/Debug](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/GSAC_startDebugging.htm) perspective which can be used to probe the ARM register set, memory content, etc...

MDK-Lite evaluation version is available free of cost for a maximum code size of 32KB.

Linux version of MDK is not available. But Keil MDK works perfectly over [WINE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) in Ubuntu.

---

### Keil uVision MDK Installation on WINE:

***Step 1: Install wine on Ubuntu***

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

***Step 2: Download [Keil MDK](https://www.keil.com/demo/eval/arm.htm).***

***Step 3: Install MDK***

Right-Click on *MDK* executable file and select "*Open With Wine Windows Program Loader*" option.

***Step 4: Invoke Keil uVision MDK on Ubuntu***

Open a terminal and type:

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Keil/UV4/Uv4.exe
```

***Step 5: Install Flash Magic (Optional)***

Flash Magic is a tool used to download software for Keil boards. Download [Flash Magic Software](http://www.flashmagictool.com/) and install it on wine (refer previous steps).

Create a COM1 link to serial port. Open a terminal and type:

```
ln -s /dev/ttyS0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/COM1
```

---

### Keil uVision MDK Project Creation and Debugging:

***Step 1: Create a Keil UVision project for ARM7 target.***

In Keil UVision tool bar select *Project --> New Project*.

Navigate to a location where you want to create this project.

Enter a project name and click *Save*.

Select *ARM --> ARM7(Little Endian)* as device for Target. Click OK.

***Step 2: Create an assembly source file for the target***

In Keil UVision tool bar select *File --> New*. Add the following code to the newly created file:

```
    AREA text, code, readonly
    ENTRY

    MOV    R0, #5
    ADD    R0, R0, #1

    END
```

Provide tab-space before each assembly statement as done above. Save the file with *'.s'* extension.

***Step 3: Add source file to project***

In Project window (located left side of UVision), Right click on *Source Group 1* and select "*Add Files to Group Source Group 1*" option.

Select *test.s* and click *'Add'*. (Select File Type as *ASM Source file*)

[image]

***Step 4: Build source file***

In Keil UVision tool bar select *Project --> Build target* or Press *F7* to compile the source file.

***Step 5: Simulate/Debug application***

In Keil UVision tool bar select *Debug--> Start/Stop Debug Session* or Press *Ctrl + F5*.

The debug perspective opens up with a Register view at left side, Code View at center, Memory view at right bottom, etc...

[image]

Use the debugging keys to execute the code:

[image]

Observe Register view at end of program execution:

[image]

In Keil UVision tool bar select *Debug--> Start/Stop Debug Session* or Press *Ctrl + F5* to come out of Debugging Perspective.

Answer (score 10):

If you build it into an actual executable then you can use [QEMU](http://qemu.org/)'s ARM emulator to run it.

Comment: I had already installed QEMU, but not sure the of the other steps.

Comment: @evening Could you please specifiy in your question in what steps you are interested? Actually Ignacio answered your question in your original post: Yes it is possible using QEMU. If you want to know about further steps, simply specify them. Do you have trouble cross compiling the ARM assembly to machine code or do you have problems starting QEMU or ...

Comment: +1 for QEMU! QEMU is a fantastic tool that is largely underestimated.

Answer (score 3):

you could run arm code through QEMU that is an emulator but I don't think you can output directly to another pice of software because QEMU is also a software but you could use something like shared memory or even a file (warning concurrent access to a file may require a mutex) to pass results from the emulator to the host software and back even if it could be a little slow

Comment: You can run *gdb* on the QEMU ARM machine.  No need to transfer data.

Answer (score 3):

This article gives a step by step introduction into using QEMU for simulating baremetal ARM code:
http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/

Of course you don't need to take care of the C stuff and can place your assembly directly in the startup.s

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're after is a way to `printf` the value returned by an ARM assembly function, from a C program. You can do this using the command-line simulator `arm-elf-run` available with **arm-elf-gcc** toolchain. You can download the toolchain from http://www.gnuarm.com/bu-2.16.1_gcc-4.0.2-c-c++_nl-1.14.0_gi-6.4_x86-64.tar.bz2. (Just unpack the archive into some folder, and optionally append `<path>/gunarm-4.0.2/bin/` to your system's `PATH` variable)

To start with, you need to arrange your ARM code into an assembly function inside an assembly (.s) file, say `myasm.s`. Now you need to write a test code in C (`test.c`, for instance) to call the assembly function and printf the returned value using our familiar `printf()`. You can find the source code below:

myasm.s:

```
                .align
                .global myasmfunc       @ Required, so that this func can be 
                                        @ accessed from main() in test.c

                                        @ A sample asm function that 
                                        @ returns the value 6
myasmfunc:      MOV     R0, #5
                ADD     R0, R0, #1      @ Now R0 contains 6.
                                        @ By the default ARM calling convention, 
                                        @ R0 will be used to pass return values
                                        @ to the calling function

                MOV     PC, LR          @ Return from myasmfunc()
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myasmfunc(void);

int main()
{
    int retval = myasmfunc();           // The value that was in R0 now 
                                        // gets copied into retval

    printf("retval = %d\n", retval);    // And print it..

    return 0;
}
```

Once the two files are ready, you can build them into an ARM binary using `arm-elf-gcc`

```
arm-elf-gcc -Wall test.c myasm.s -o test.out
```

And then run the binary using `arm-elf-run`

```
arm-elf-run ./test.out
```

This will print a `retval = 6` on your Ubuntu terminal :)

Comment: Gnuarm [site lists](http://www.gnuarm.com/resources.html) several simulators: [SkyEye](http://www.skyeye.org/), [SWARM](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mwd24/phd/swarm.html) and [Armphetamine](http://armphetamine.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @osgx: The link I've posted directly downloads the required gnuarm.tar.bz2 archive. Alternatively, you can find this link in the Binaries section under the FILES tab (http://www.gnuarm.com/files.html) of gnuarm site, and not under http://www.gnuarm.com/resources.html. By 'command-line simulator', I meant the 'arm-elf-run' program found inside the tarball under the /bin/ folder. Please see my edit

Comment: nav, Yes, you posted gnuarm's simulator. But their site lists several other simulators too. `arm-elf-run` is arm simulator from GDB, and its readme file from 1995 says that project is a copy of "standard release of the [ARMulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMulator) from Advanced RISC Machines" and gives link: ftp.cl.cam.ac.uk/arm/gnu

Comment: Well osgx, I honestly don't know anything about the other simulators mentioned over there; and I'm not an expert on this matter either :). Regarding `arm-elf-run`, the main reason I suggested it is because of its decent support for `printf()`; you can insert `printf()`s inside bare metal code and try to print any message, `arm-elf-run` will happily output those on your Linux terminal. I haven't seen this kind of flexibility with other simulators and toolchains (such as Codesourcery arm-none-eabi, for instance)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code in this git repository as a starting point:

https://github.iu.edu/geobrown/c335-assembly-examples

As others have mentioned you'll first need to install QEMU to emulate the ARM hardware and you will need to have some way of compiling your code (I recommend the [CodeSourcery Lite Edition Toolchain](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/)).  Then edit the `TOOLROOT` entry in the `Makefile.common` file to point to the installation location of your toolchain and simply run the command `make test` after you have written your assembly code and externed it into your C test file.

The code in this repository provides a bunch of examples that you can adapt to your own purposes and the C test files will allow you to call your assembly code and output the results to your terminal in Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 1):

I always use a small qemu ARM  VM to test ARM programs.

You can download it from [debian](http://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armel/) and then run it with: ([more infos](http://www.red-lang.org/2012/03/setting-up-arm-virtual-machine.html))

```
qemu-system-arm  -localtime -m 256 -M versatilepb -kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-versatile -initrd initrd.img-2.6.32-5-versatile -hda debian_squeeze_armel_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1" $@
```

Since it simulates a full arm system, you can write the programs on it (e.g. with vim + gcc) and then test them there.

Answer (score 0):

Install qemu, cross compile it for arm, and then use

```
qemu-system-arm ./a.out
```

on your terminal

Comment: what file format is expected by `qemu-system-arm`? Will it start elf file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why noone has mentioned it yet, but you can get a ***"real" and affordable arm platform*** to experiment with, with **[Raspberry pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)**.

It doesn't come with Ubuntu by default, [to my knowledge it come's with a Debian remix called Raspbian *(but can also run Fedora, Arch or Debian plain)*](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

When it comes for support of that platform, there are [books](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Pi-Assembly-Language-Beginners/dp/148112790X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359985103&sr=8-1) for that and it even has [its own Stack Exchange sub community](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to write an ARM emulator in C, you can use the code in this repository as a starting point.
https://github.com/omufeed/ARMAssemblyEmulatorWithC
It has a pipeline of size 4. Data processing instructions are implemented and it handles the overflow and carry flags. Branch and interrupts are also implemented.
It accepts an assembly instruction as input and simulates the final memory state after the instruction completion.
There are some example inputs added as code comments.
Read more at http://www.omidmufeed.com/arm-assembler-emulator-with-c/